# How to add the zeit env variables properly

Tags: reactjs, deployment, next.js, vercel

I have a nextJS application and using zeit for deployments. Which is integrated with github. The env variables are working locally. But it gives an error when we are deploying it.

1. Created remotely in the zeit console. And pull them to local environment.

   - Created on the console
   - Pulled to local

     `now env pull`
   - It creates an `.env` file inside the root directory.
   - Results of `now env ls`

   [image]

   - Results of  `now secrets list`

   [image]

   - Added value to the `now.json`

   ```
   {
       "env": {
           "TEST_ENV": "@test-env",
       }
   }
   ```

   - Installed `dotenv-webpack` module
   - included it to the `next.config.js`

     `config.plugins.push(new Dotenv({ silent: true }));`
   - Added to the config of `next.config.js` file

```
const config = {
   pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
   env: {
      TEST_ENV: process.env.TEST_ENV,
   },
};
```

- This is working locally. But when we are deploying it doesn't work. The git give the following response.
  [image]

Comment: The line `"TEST_ENV": "@test-env",` means you want `TEST_ENV` to be the value of the [secret](https://vercel.com/docs/now-cli#commands/secrets) `test-env`. You never created that secret but I assume you created the ENV called `TEST_ENV`

Comment: Thanks for replying. Did you notice the screenshot of the result of `now secrets list`. It indicates that I have created that secret.

Comment: Not sure if `test-env` would equal `test-env-develepment-something`

Comment: What is the right command for creating a secret in the local, how do we make the "Preview" and "Prod" envs aware about it.

`now secrets add test-env test-value` ? How do we publish it to prev and prod

Comment: `test-env-develepment-something` this create automaticaly when we hit the following command. `now env add test_env`